# Regex for dot in a String appearing maximum once

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to write a regex for a `"." in String appearing maximum once` in a String

So for e.g.

```
Nick.Div is Valid
NickDiv is Valid
Nick.Div. is Invalid
Nic.k.Div is Invalid
```

I have tried a few examples but all failed. I would really appreciate your help on this as I am super bad with RegEx. The online tutorials confused me even more.

Comment: you need a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: @MarcB Well how would I use that look around, it seems it is ultimately a Regex. Actually more confusing than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to match either a string that is all non-dot characters:

```
^[^.]*$
```

or a string that is non-dot characters, followed by a `.`, followed by non-dot characters:

```
^[^.]*\.[^.]*$
```

We can combine those into one regex:

```
^[^.]*(?:\.[^.]*)?$
```

That is:

```
^         # beginning of string
[^.]*     # 0 or more non-. characters
(?:       # start of a (non-capturing) group
  \.      # a literal .
  [^.]*   # 0 or more non-. characters
)?        # end of group, which is optional (appears 0 or 1 times)
$         # end of string
```

Comment: I want a String that in all has one or less "." characters in it.

Comment: @NickDiv Yes ... I know? I mean, that's what your question said, so that's what I gave you. I'm very confused by your comment.

Comment: But in your answer it says 1. All non-dot characters 2. Non-dot character followed by "." and then again followed by non-dot

Comment: @NickDiv Yes, which is equivalent to 1. no dots and 2. exactly one dot in the string.

Comment: In your regex shouldn't there be an extra slash i,e. ^[^.]*(?:\\.[^.]*)?$ or what you have is correct.

Comment: What would the extra backslash be there for?

Comment: I think to escape the special character and treat it as actually part of the string as dot is one special character? Like I said I am not sure. i guess depends on where I am using it. In Java double backslash is used to escape a special character from a string.

Comment: What string? What I gave you is the raw regex. Are you trying to embed it in Java? (Your question doesn't mention a programming language.)

Comment: Yes it is a regex that will be passed to an annotation. Do not worry about it. I will post the result in a 2 minutes.

Comment: Your regex works absolutely fine in fiddle but not in Java String, I guess Ill have to modify my question and post another one. But thanks.