# Regex to use in Pattern annotation for dot appearing maximum once.

Tags: java, regex, validation

I want a Regex that I want to use in Java Pattern annotation to match with a String that contains maximum one dot.

I found a Regex that works outside Java here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37890308/1787314

I am not sure why but the Regex doesn't seem to work when passed in the Pattern annotation.

```
@Pattern(regex = "^[^.]*(?:\\.[^.]*)?$")
private String name;
```

This is the behavior that I am expecting.

```
Nick.Div -- Matches
NickDiv -- Matches
Nick.Div. -- Doesn't Match
Nic.k.Div -- Doesn't Match
```

I tried manipulating the Regex a bit inside the annotation but all failed.

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Why not split on your full stop, then only accept resultant arrays with two elements?

Comment: But I want to use the Pattern annotation. I cannot use code like split or contains etc. to do the validation.

Comment: Count the number of matches you get, if it is below 1, accept that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
"^[^.]*\\.[^.]*$"
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hX7nS6/1)

- `"` delimiter
- `^` first of string
- `[^.]*` a character class which matches zero or more of everything except `.`
- `\\.` matches a dot `.` literally
- `$` end of string